# Using SHACL to validate if one specific language tag is present in repeated annotation properties

Tags: validation, ontology, knowledge-graph, shacl

we would like to specify for our ontology, that each class must at least have a `skos:definition` in English, but translations (also described as `skos:definition` with a different language tag) are welcome. I would like to specify a SHACL-Shape to check if that condition is met.

A simple valid example of a class definition:

```
ex:ExampleClass a owl:Class ;
  skos:definition "An example Class"@en, "Eine Beispielklasse"@de .
```

The only thing I found which seemed helpful in that area is `sh:languageIn`. Unfortunately, as I understand it, it only checks if all language tags are part of a given set.

```
ex:Pattern1 a sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:targetClass owl:Class ;
  sh:property [
    sh:path skos:definition ;
    sh:datatype rdf:langString ;
    sh:languageIn (
      "en"
    ) ;
  ] .
```

Unfortunately, stackoverflows spam filter seems to hinder me from posting the ttl blocks with prefixes. Therefore, I provide that in a gist: https://gist.github.com/MattTJung/8739566f550c85d9ab3c862267a7675b

How can I alter this, to make sure there is at least one occurence of `@en`, but still allow for other language tags?

Comment: This sounds like a use case for Qualified Value Shapes, see https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ontology-modeling-shacl-qualified-cardinality-holger-knublauch-zp8hf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint given by @HolgerKnublauch pushed me on the right path, thank you.

```
ex:Pattern1 a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetClass owl:Class ;
    sh:property [
      sh:path skos:definition ;
      sh:qualifiedMinCount 1;
      sh:qualifiedValueShape [
        sh:datatype rdf:langString ;
        sh:languageIn ( "en" ) ;
      ] ;
    ] .
```